# mtlanius theme issue - Site move from development to production server

Tags: magento, themes

Site move error:

1) We moved the entire site (zip format) and extracted on server.

2) Created the database instance

3) Updated the database urls in config table and local.xml updated with new details.

When I check in browser, it executes site correctly but templates settings and sliders images tables are deleted and recreated with default entries, because "sql" folder has commands like :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('mtslideshow_slide')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('mtslideshow_slide')}

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('mtslideshow_category')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('mtslideshow_category')}
```

Same for some content pages also footer etc are roll backed to default.

How to deal with this issue?
Here I'm facing this issue: http://demo.aarnasystems.net/magento/lacxodemo/index.php/
Logo slider, Amasty filter settings, footer design changes are rolled back.

Please let me know, how to avoid to reinitializing the modules on database connection.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

But you did copy the entire database to a new server? Because if in core_resource table there would be entry for mtslideshow extension with the same version that it had on the last server, then sql shouldn't be run again.